# Why do we need abstract methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have been studying abstract methods lately and I can't understand why do we need them? 
I mean, after all, we are just overriding them. Do you know its just a declaration? Why do we need them?

Also, I tried understanding this from the internet and everywhere there's an explanation like imagine there's an abstract class human then there're its subclasses **disabled** and **not disabled** then the abstract function in human class `walking()` will contain different body or code. Now what I am saying is why don't we just create a function in the disabled and not disabled subclasses instead of overriding. Thus again back to the question in the first paragraph. Please explain it.

Comment: You can't call nor otherwise use something that's not declared.

Comment: im saying why declare it in the abstract class instead just go and make a function in the subclass? Whats the need of abstract method(there must be some and I want to know it)?

Comment: `abstract` members mandate that subclasses override them. Without abstract, you may forget to override it when writing a subclass later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the most obvious uses of abstract methods is letting the abstract class call them from an implementation of other methods.

Here is an example:

```
class AbstractToy {
    protected abstract String getName();
    protected abstract String getSize();
    public String getDescription() {
        return "This is a really "+getSize()+" "+getName();
    }
}
class ToyBear extends AbstractToy {
    protected override String getName() { return "bear"; }
    protected override String getSize() { return "big"; }
}
class ToyPenguin extends AbstractToy {
    protected override String getName() { return "penguin"; }
    protected override String getSize() { return "tiny"; }
}
```

Note how `AbstractToy`'s implementation of `getDescription` is able to call `getName` and `getSize`, even though the definitions are in the subclasses. This is an instance of a well-known design pattern called [*Template Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 5):

The abstract method definition in a base type is a contract that guarantees that every concrete implementation of that type will have an implementation of that method.

Without it, the compiler wouldn't allow you to call that method on a reference of the base-type, because it couldn't guarantee that such a method will always be there.

So if you have

```
MyBaseClass x = getAnInstance();
x.doTheThing();
```

and `MyBaseClass` **doesn't** have a `doTheThing` method, then the compiler will tell you that it can't let you do that. By adding an *abstract* `doTheThing` method you guarantee that every concrete implementation that `getAnInstance()` can return has an implementation, which is good enough for the compiler, so it'll let you call that method.

Basically a more fundamental truth, that needs to be groked first is this:

You will have instances where the *type of the variable is more general than the type of the value it holds*. In simple cases you can just make the variable be the specific type:

```
MyDerivedClassA a = new MyDerivcedClassA();
```

In that case you could obviously call any method of `MyDerivedClassA` and wouldn't need any abstract methods in the base class.

But sometimes you want to do a thing with *any* `MyBaseClass` instance and you *don't know* what specific type it is:

```
public void doTheThingsForAll(Collection<? extends MyBaseClass> baseClassReferences) {
  for (MyBaseClass myBaseReference : baseClassReferences) {
    myBaseReference.doTheThing();
  }
}
```

If your `MyBaseClass` didn't have the `doTheThing` abstract method, then the compiler wouldn't let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

To continue with your example, at some point you might have a List of humans, and you don't really care whether they are disabled or not, all you care about is that you want to call the walking() method on them. In order to do that, the Human class needs to define a walking() method. However, you might not know how to implement that without knowing whether the human is or isn't disabled. So you leave the implementation to the inheriting classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples of *how* you'd use this in the other answers, so let me give some explanation of *why* you might do this.

First, one common rule of Object Oriented Design is that you should, in general, try to program to interfaces rather than specific implementations. This tends to improve the program's flexibility and maintainability if you need to change some behavior later. For example, in one program I wrote, we were writing data to CSV files. We later decided to switch to writing to Excel files instead. Programming to interfaces (rather than a specific implementation) made it a lot easier for us to make this change because we could just "drop in" a new class to write to Excel files in place of the class to write to CSV files.

You probably haven't studied this yet, but this is actually important for certain [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). A few notable examples of where this is potentially helpful are the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), and the [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

For context, a Design Pattern is a standard way of describing and documenting a solution to a known problem. If, for example, someone says "you should use the strategy pattern to solve this problem," this makes the general idea of how you should approach the problem clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes we need a method that should behave differently in its instances.

For example, imagine a class `Animal` which contains a method `Shout`.
We are going to have different instances of this `Animal` class but we need to implement the method differently in some cases like below:

```
class Animal:
    /**
       different properties and methods
       which are shared between all animals here
    */
    ...

    method shout():
        pass

class Dog extends Animal:
    method shout():
        makeDogVoice()

class Cat extends Animal:
    method shout():
        makeCatVoice()


dog = new Animal
cat = new Animal

dog.shout()
cat.shout()
```

So dog shouts like dogs, and cat shouts like cats! Without implementing the shared behaviors twice

There is a different behavior of shouting in these instances. So we need abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you don't know about implementation and still want to declare a method then we can do that with the help of abstract modifier and making it an abstract method. For abstract method only declaration is available but not the implementation. Hence they should end with `;`

**Example:**

```
public abstract void m1(); // this is correct 
public abstract void m1(){  ...  } // this is wrong
```

**Advantage:** By declaring abstract method in parent class we can provide guideline to child classes such that which methods are compulsory to implement.

Example:

```
abstract class Vehicle{
  abstract int getNoOfWheels();
}

Class Bus extends Car{
  public int getNoOfWheels(){
     return 4;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the short answer, think of this:

You have an abstract class `Car`.

You implement 2 classes that extend it, `Ferrari` and `Mercedes`.

Now:
What if you did one of the following, for the method `drive()`, common to all cars:

1) changed the visibility of the method,

2) changed the name of the method from driving to Driving,

3) changed the return type, from a boolean to an int

Think about it. It might not seem to make any difference right, because they are different implementations?

**Wrong!**

If I am iterating through an array of cars, I would have to call a different method for each type of car, thereby making this implementation of abstract useless.

Abstract classes are there to group classes with a common template, that share common properties. One way this helps would be the looping over the array:
Abstract methods ensure that all cars declare the same method, 
and therefore, any object of a subclass of `Car` will have the method `drive()`, as defined in the abstract class, making the for loop mentioned easy to implement.

Hope this helps.